# why nginx load phtml files as html files

Tags: nginx

My sites runs perfectly on apache server.Now i am tring to implement on nginx server and i have problem like my magento's phtml files executes as html.I tried and added "*.phtml" extension in nginx config file but not succeed.

here my config file

```
cat /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com 

server {
listen 80 default_server;

root /usr/share/nginx/mydomain.com/;
index index.php index.phtml index.html index.htm;

server_name mydomain.com ;
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
}

location ~ /(mysite|framework|cms)/.*\.(phtml|inc)$ {
    deny all;
}
}
```

Please suggest how can i solve ".html" file to ".phtml" in nginx?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was cross-posted to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810806/why-nginx-load-phtml-files-as-html-files%22

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your phtml files are PHP, they would need to be interpreted by php-fpm as with your php files so this should work:

```
location ~ \.(php|phtml)$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
}
```

Comment: already i asked here "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47810806/why-nginx-load-phtml-files-as-html-files"

Comment: Where are the phtml files located? If they're in the location following then they wouldn't be accessed externally. As I understand it Magento uses the extension for presentation templates. 
Revert to the previous location snippet, copy it and replace `php` with `phtml` to ensure that they're working separately. Also check your php-fpm logs for any errors.